# Pause or wait after playing audio clips

Tags: typescript, audio, delay, pause

I'm trying to get a random delay of between 5 to 10 seconds after an audio file has been played but it won't work and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried everything from `setTimeout` to `setInterval`.

I just want this to play random audio files with random delays between the given time.

Is there a simpler way?

```html
<body style="background-image: url(image/funky.gif)">
<audio id="myaudio" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sounds = new Array();
    sounds[0]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/2.mp3";
    sounds[1]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/3.mp3";
    sounds[2]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/5.mp3";   
    sounds[3]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/7.mp3";
    sounds[4]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/Zombie Back From Dead.mp3";
    sounds[5]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/Zombie-Aggressive-Attack-A9.wav";
    sounds[6]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/zombie-growl.mp3";
    sounds[7]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/zombie-monster-beast.mp3";
    sounds[8]="https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/zombie-walk.mp3";

    function getRandomSounds() {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
        document.getElementById("myaudio").src = sounds[randomNum];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(5,10));
              GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    
    }
    document.getElementById("myaudio").addEventListener("ended", getRandomSounds);
    getRandomSounds();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where are all of the objects in `WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(5,10));
              GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play()` defined, please? If you're using TS, you might want to tag it as such instead of JS.

Comment: I've attempted my own solution with some research and after deleting a few lines I think I forgot to delete these lines as well. Now that I think about it, that makes more sense as to why the sounds stopped playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach to waiting in JS is to resolve a promise after some delay created by `setTimeout`, then chain your logic on it:

```js
const wait = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
;
const rand = (lo, hi) => ~~(Math.random() * (hi - lo)) + lo;

const baseURL = "https://plplatoon.com/homebrew/wav/";
const sounds = [
  "2.mp3", "3.mp3", "5.mp3", "7.mp3",
  "Zombie Back From Dead.mp3",
  "Zombie-Aggressive-Attack-A9.wav",
  "zombie-growl.mp3",
  "zombie-monster-beast.mp3",
  "zombie-walk.mp3",
].map(e => baseURL + e);

const playRandomSound = () => {
  audioEl.src = sounds[rand(0, sounds.length)];
};

const audioEl = document.querySelector("audio");
audioEl.addEventListener("ended", async () => {
  await wait(rand(5000, 10000));
  playRandomSound();
});
playRandomSound();
```

```html
<audio id="myaudio" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's much neater than what I could come up with. I've still much to learn.